# Ambiguity when inheriting ostringstream

Tags: c++

I have a simple struct which inherits from `std::ostringstream`, in order to handle some values better for databases. If I just inherit, and add in a simple constructor to set widths for precision of doubles, it works fine.

```cpp
struct myostream : std::ostringstream {
    myostream() noexcept( false ) {
        this->precision( 6 );
        this->setf( ios_base::fixed, ios_base::floatfield );
    }
};
```

Now, I'm trying to add in an `operator<<` for type `double`, in order to handle infinity, and NaN.

```cpp
myostream &operator<<( double val ) {
    if ( std::isnan( val ) ) {
        *static_cast<std::ostringstream *>( this ) << "'NaN'";
    } else if ( std::isinf( val ) ) {
        *static_cast<std::ostringstream *>( this ) << ( val < 0 ? "'-Infinity'" : "'Infinity'" );
    } else {
        *static_cast<std::ostringstream *>( this ) << val;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

As soon as I add this function in, I just get ambiguous function calls everywhere, for every type (`bool`, `char`, `char *`, `int`, etc.).

```
2>...\include\myostream.hpp(13,14): message : could be 'myostream &myostream::operator <<(double)' (compiling source file ...)
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30704\include\ostream(694,32): message : or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,char)' (compiling source file ...)
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30704\include\ostream(775,31): message : or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,char)' (compiling source file ...)
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30704\include\ostream(856,32): message : or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,_Elem)'
2>        with
2>        [
2>            _Elem=char
2>        ] (compiling source file ...)
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30704\include\ostream(898,31): message : or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,signed char)' (compiling source file ...)
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30704\include\ostream(909,31): message : or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,unsigned char)' (compiling source file ...)
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30704\include\thread(275,26): message : or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,std::thread::id)' (compiling source file ...)
2>...: message : or       'built-in C++ operator<<(int, int)'
2>...: message : while trying to match the argument list '(myostream, char)'
```

So, my question is: how would I go about overriding `operator<<` for some types, without adding in ambiguity? Is this even possible, or would I need to make a function which returns a string instead?

Edit:
Adding in `using std::ostringstream::operator<<;` just increases the number of ambiguities.

Comment: If you actually use the `myostream` for anything, it's reproducible: https://godbolt.org/z/sfxjr77xP

Comment: Since you are overloading `double`, why is the type of `char` passed in? If you call `double`, there will be [no problem](https://godbolt.org/z/h63f1rKrK).

Comment: @康桓瑋, the point is to make it work with all existing types that `ostringstream` supports, but just change how it handles double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
struct myostream : std::ostringstream {
    using std::ostringstream::operator<<;    // bring in all the member overloads
    
    myostream() noexcept( false ) {
        this->precision( 6 );
        this->setf( ios_base::fixed, ios_base::floatfield );
    }

    // call the base class member function explicitly in here:
    myostream &operator<<( double val ) {
        if ( std::isnan( val ) ) {
            std::ostringstream::operator<<("'NaN'");
        } else if ( std::isinf( val ) ) {
            std::ostringstream::operator<<( val < 0 ? "'-Infinity'" : "'Infinity'" );
        } else {
            std::ostringstream::operator<<(val);
        }
        return *this;
    }    
};

// front-end for all the free operator<< functions:
// (this could be narrowed down to not match on T:s that isn't supported)
template<class T>
myostream& operator<<(myostream& m, const T& x) {
    static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(m) << x;
    return m;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work with it? It worked for all my test cases :/

Comment: @ChrisMM  I haven't caught the actual `NaN`'s. Seems important in this case :-)

Comment: @ChrisMM Oh my ... I tested with `NAN` which is `float`. It works with `double f =  NAN;` and output that.  I'll take back my claim that it doesn't work :-)

Comment: Oh, I have another overload for `float` (was just using double as example)

Comment: @ChrisMM :-) That explains it. If there are misses in this I wouldn't be surprised though. Let me know if you find problems. Just unaccept and leave a note if you have some info about what's not working.

Answer (score 2):

When the type of `T` is not `double` such as `char`, it will be implicitly converted to `double` and call `myostream::operator<<`, but since `ostream::operator<<` has `char` overload, `myostream` will also be implicitly converted to `ostream` and call base's `operator<<`, so there is ambiguity here.

You can use SFINAE to prevent the implicit conversion of `double` in `myostream::operator<<` when `T` is not a `double`:

```
template<class T>
inline std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, double>, myostream&>
operator<<(myostream& os, T val ) {
  if ( std::isnan( val ) ) {
      static_cast<std::ostringstream &>( os ) << "'NaN'";
  } else if ( std::isinf( val ) ) {
      static_cast<std::ostringstream &>( os ) << ( val < 0 ? "'-Infinity'" : "'Infinity'" );
  } else {
      static_cast<std::ostringstream &>( os ) << val;
  }
  return os;
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/P5zM5zT8E)

Comment: That seems to work with every type except `bool`. Even if I add in the `&& !std::is_same_v<T,bool>` into the template condition. https://godbolt.org/z/1qbcd5Ecc

Comment: @ChrisMM. Fixed, the problem is that `ostream` also has member `operator<<` functions, so the workaround is to just define `operator<<` as a friend function instead of the member function.